# Destination Host Unreachable Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping

I have two FPGAs configured with IP addresses, 172.17.0.106 and 172.17.0.107. I connected these FPGAs to the Ubuntu PC via etherent. I set static IP address for these ethernet connections as shown below,

Settings for FPGA 1:

[image: Settings for FPGA 1]

Settings for FPGA 2:

[image: Settings for FPGA 2]

The problem I am having is, I can only connect to one at a time but not both. It used to work before, for some reason it doesn't work now. For the same configuration above works in my Windows laptop without any issues.

ping output for FPGA 1:

[image: ping output for FPGA 1]

`ping` output for FPGA:

[image: ping output for FPGA 2]

Some references below:

`if config` :

[image: if config]

Route table:

[image: Route table]

Comment: You are aware the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS goes EOL at the end of May? It was scheduled for the end of April but they extended it by 1 month.